# Delphi: DKLang: can someone fix issue with 2 forms of the same class

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

[DKLang](http://www.dk-soft.org) is Localization package. I have an old issue when 2 or more forms of the same class aren't translated (only 1st of them is translated, others are in English). I mean forms created dynamically.

Can someone fix this? Author of DKlang doesn't respond for year.

EDIT
How to see in action: demo project (6KB RAR, source only) [download here](http://yadi.sk/d/TLuNRcKD4MD1l).
After compiling, press main button- you'll see 3 instances of sample form, 1st is localized, others 2 are not. Requires non-Unicode Delphi + TNT Unicode Controls + [DKLang](http://www.dk-soft.org/dlink.php?id=74&lang=en) 3.x

[image: Demo project]

Comment: License allows you to do it yourself. What did you try?

Comment: I tried to look into source, cannot understand code, so can't fix the issue. If some good component writer can understand it, I appreciate it, much.

Comment: You have not fully described the issue. If you really cared about this, you would supply a complete reproduction of the problem.

Comment: I added DEMO RAR (source only) to 1st post. It's seen after compiling demo and pressing a btn.

Comment: There are official support forums, tried to use it ? http://www.dk-soft.org/talk/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=9 and https://sourceforge.net/projects/dklang/forums/forum/898834 Icon looks you use outdated Delphi 7 while trunk DKLang does require D2009+. Thus perhaps author realyl is no more iunterested in outdated programs. But on  forum there should be other users.

Comment: Try in Form2.FormCreate or FormShow use TDKLanguageManager ApplyTranToController to Form2 self.DKLanguageController1

Comment: I tried adding LangManager.TranslateController call, or LangManager.ApplyTranToController, after making them public, no help...

Comment: 1) Forums of DKLang - can't find SignUp link so can't post. seems forums are inactive. Forum @sf.net is empty. 2) "DKLang does require D2009"-- seems D7 version also OK, D2009 version is just port to Unicod.

Comment: DKLang 4 is told to require 2009. And if you cannot be co-developer, then you better believe it and use DKLang 3. Or be co-developer and back-port DKLang4 to D7 if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems i found it. My fix is two new lines in TDKLang_CompTranslations.FindComponentName
which are for names "Form2_1", "Form2_2"

```
function TDKLang_CompTranslations.FindComponentName(sComponentName: String): TDKLang_CompTranslation;
  var idx: Integer;
  begin
    idx := Pos('_', sComponentName); //added
    if idx>0 then System.Delete(sComponentName, idx, MaxInt); //added

    idx := IndexOfComponentName(sComponentName);
    if idx<0 then Result := nil else Result := GetItems(idx);
  end;
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a pretty old question now, but for the records, I want to give the right answer.
The DKLanguageController has a **SectionName** property.
When playing with forms or frames that will be dynamically instantiated, give SectionName a value. This value will be common to all instances of the owner forms/frames.
All the translations will be stored under a section named with the **SectionName** value, instead of the **name** of the form/frame.
This is clearly stated in the documentation, no need to mess with the source code.

Comment: No, need to mess. I posted issue to DKL developer. He agreed it is bug. fixed.

Comment: I can't believe it. I use DKLang 3.01 (date of source code: 2006). I have multiple cases like the one you exposed, and never had any problem thanks to the SectionName property

Comment: still he agreed it's issue. Github page of DKL

Comment: True, I found it on github. But it was useless to do that because SectionName exists. I still consider there was no need "to mess" with source. My downvoted answer is correct and it respects the functional design of DKLang. Try it yourself and you'll see.

Comment: but it bad to set SectionName for each form. For each with 2 objects. I still think i don't want to set SectionName